# How to overwrite the CSS for A Struts 2 theme (applied to individual JSP-s - not overall)

Tags: css, struts2, themes

I have applied a custom theme to a particular JSP page in my project.
The Struts FAQ says that CSS can be overwritten by adding a css file to the header of the JSP page. Is there any way I can just overwrite the `styles.css` file so that the overwritten file is used wherever I use the custom theme?

I though it would be as simple as editing the `styles.css` of my custom theme as it uses the xhtml theme as its parent theme, and each file in the custom theme overwrite the files of the same name in the xhtml theme.

Comment: At the end of the day it is just a normal web page, if the style isn't defined in the header or on the tags it won't work.

Comment: Good point. Thanks for the help